# How to intuitively explain the role of transistors in boolean logic and switching?

Tags: undergraduate-education

Boolean logic is easily explained using truth tabels, but the underlying hardware is rarely mentioned in the same class. I would like to explain boolean logic from the point of view of actual transistor. My target audience is educated adults with no background in engineering, for a one-time public lecture. The goal is to have them understand why a [simple cut-wire alarm circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/36810/how-can-i-design-a-circuit-that-will-turn-on-when-a-wire-is-cut) is designed the way it's designed, and without going "deep" into solid state physics.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you actually want? Ideas for explaining the role of transistors? Material for it? Experiences with such explanations? Is this going to be a public lecture or something of that kind or part of a longer course?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta, I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use transistor logic?  Or would diodes and resistors be sufficient?

Comment: You can also explain boolean logic gates using "the human visual system."  See [Mark Changizi's paper](http://www.changizi.com/viscomp.pdf).

Comment: You can also explain boolean logic gates using [billiard balls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billiard-ball_computer).

Comment: Well, what you'll actually be doing in this approach is explaining how transistors implement boolean logic. And you don't need to explain the solid-state physics behind transistors, but you do need to explain the high-level switching models. But you haven't even said what transistors you want to use: FETs, BJTs, etc.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff, I was thinking of a black box approach, but based on FET.

Comment: In that case you can inspire yourself from http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_3/chpt_5/2.html Alas their page on MOSFET/IGFET is not yet done.

Answer (score 2):

You can explain them as electrically controllable switches.

- If a voltage is applied to gate and source, this means `switched on`: Current may flow between drain and source. Or voltage is transferred through the transistor.
- If no voltage is applied, this means `switched off`: No current may flow resp. voltage is blocked.

Comment: Yeah, but things get complicated depending which type of transistor you're taking about. This is a good explanation for FETs but not for BJTs. I feel this question is not really at home on this site.

Answer (score 1):

This may be off the mark of your question, but I have explained
logic gates composed of (transistor) switches by using water pressure
as analogous to electricity.
Below, water will only reach the pipe-end $C$ if water pressure comes
in both along pipe $A$ AND there is water pressure
from $B$ that pushes up and closes the normally open switch, connecting $A$ to $C$.

---

[image: WaterSwitch]

---

If either there is no water pressure at $A$, or there is no water pressure at $B$, 
no water reaches $C$.
So this is an AND-gate. Etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could follow the suggestions made in the other posts, but I would start with an even simpler model which you could build and demonstrate easily: levers.

Consider building a contraption (a la Rube Goldberg, but much more boring) of remotely flipping a light switch (where down means light is off and up means light is on).  One way to do this is to attach a long rod to the switch as follows: fix one end (use a universal joint as needed) of the rod to the switch, and fix the middle of the rod to a stationary object.  You now have a logical inverter (the other end of the rod will be up when the switch is down, and down when the switch is up).

This requires a representation (0 means down and 1 means up) and a tolerance for building more complicated contraptions (concatenate two inverters to get the Boolean identity function, take two inverters and a spring or a lead weight on the end of a third inverter and make a two input AND gate by placing the three levers in a star configuration with the weight in the center; pushing on the ends on one of two of them will cause the third end to fall), but conceptually they are very simple: this only requires people having seen a lever before, and the contraptions aren't that complex.  You will need very few levers to make a model of a transistor, and many people should make the analogy between lever position and voltage level easily.

Gerhard "Mixes Water And Electrons Mentally" Paseman, 2015.02.26

Comment: To be fair to your audience, you should mention that the transistor is not a two-state device always, and that the lever model is just to help in describing the Boolean algebra aspect.  It is possible to adapt the lever model for multistate devices, but I would not try it for a public lecture.  Gerhard "Likes To Please The Audience" Paseman, 2015.02.26